Sharp Estimates for Multilinear Fourier Multipliers with Limited Smoothness
Let $m(\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n)$ be a bounded function on $\mathbb{R}^{nd}$ that satisfies the following multilinear Hörmander-Mikhlin condition:
$$
|\partial^{\alpha} m(\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n)| \leq C_{\alpha} \prod_{j=1}^n (1 + |\xi_j|)^{-|\alpha_j|}
$$
for all multi-indices $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n)$ with $|\alpha| \leq s$, where $s$ is a positive integer.
Consider the associated multilinear Fourier multiplier operator $T_m$ defined by
$$
T_m(f_1, \dots, f_n)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{nd}} m(\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n) \hat{f}_1(\xi_1) \dots \hat{f}_n(\xi_n) e^{2\pi i x \cdot (\xi_1 + \dots + \xi_n)} d\xi_1 \dots d\xi_n
$$
where $\hat{f}_j$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f_j$.
For what range of exponents $p_1, \dots, p_n, q$ and smoothness parameter $s$ does the following inequality hold:
$$
\| T_{m}(f_1, \dots, f_n) \|_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^d)} \leq C \prod_{j=1}^{n} \| f_j \|_{L^{p_j}(\mathbb{R}^d)}
$$
Can we find sharp bounds for the constant $C$ in terms of the dimension $d$, the number of functions $n$, the exponents $p_1, \dots, p_n, q$, and the smoothness parameter $s$?
I think we can use a multilinear Calderón-Zygmund decomposition of $T_m$, leveraging the limited smoothness of $m$ to control the resulting kernel estimates. Interpolation between endpoints seems to be key.

Perhaps you could comment on what results from the literature you are already aware of?
